# how to solve 'isregisterd issue in flutter when user restorationmixin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i want to restore my data when application come from background to foreground for that i used restorationmixin in my stateful class but always i getting error regarding 'isregisterd'
[image]

i read all documentation regarding restroable documentation from here => [https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/restore-state-android#:~:text=With%20the%20RestorationManager%20%2C%20the%20Flutter,app%20only%20moments%20to%20prepare](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/restore-state-android#:%7E:text=With%20the%20RestorationManager%20%2C%20the%20Flutter,app%20only%20moments%20to%20prepare).